# Truffle Install (WARN deprecated)

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, truffle

`manuelfiestas@Manuels-MBP node_modules % npm install -g truffle
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp-promise@5.0.1: This package is broken and no longer maintained. 'mkdirp' itself supports promises now, please switch to that.
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@2.1.3: "Please update to latest v2.3 or v2.2"
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated circular-json@0.5.9: CircularJSON is in maintenance only, flatted is its successor.
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated remotedev-serialize@0.1.9: Package moved to @redux-devtools/serialize.
npm WARN deprecated redux-devtools-instrument@1.10.0: Package moved to @redux-devtools/instrument.
npm WARN deprecated redux-devtools-core@0.2.1: Package moved to @redux-devtools/app.
npm WARN deprecated ethereumjs-tx@2.1.2: New package name format for new versions: @ethereumjs/tx. Please update.
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.1: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated multicodec@0.5.7: stable api reached
npm WARN deprecated node-pre-gyp@0.11.0: Please upgrade to @mapbox/node-pre-gyp: the non-scoped node-pre-gyp package is deprecated and only the @mapbox scoped package will recieve updates in the future
npm WARN deprecated axios@0.20.0: Critical security vulnerability fixed in v0.21.1. For more information, see https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/3410
npm WARN deprecated ethereumjs-common@1.5.2: New package name format for new versions: @ethereumjs/common. Please update.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.

added 1713 packages, and audited 1714 packages in 1m

96 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

53 vulnerabilities (16 low, 8 moderate, 29 high)

To address all issues, run:
npm audit fix

Run `npm audit` for details.
manuelfiestas@Manuels-MBP node_modules %`

Answer (score 0):

delete all files you have in your filesystem from old failed installations and try again

Comment: How can I access my failed installations? I'm not too familiar with the terminal but am trying to learn :)

Comment: search in the folder, which you write in your question

Comment: I've deleted both npm and truffle folders. Now I reinstalled truffle and got a 18 "deprecated" errors and it just seems I'm running into more issues.

Answer (score 0):

The answer below stands for a manual installation, but there is a much simpler way : the automatic install.

Open Powershell as admin and run **`npm install -g windows-build-tools`**

The install takes time but **it worked.**